specific.avro.record when set to true doesnt consume the message
This is my config. Tried many things, but not able to consume.
properties.setProperty("key.deserializer", StringDeserializer.class.getName());
        properties.setProperty("value.deserializer", KafkaAvroDeserializer.class.getName());
        properties.setProperty("specific.avro.reader", "true");


and this as well .properties.setProperty("schema.registry.url", "http://"); // replace with your Schema Registry URL

Setup log4j and please share your logs and full consumer code as [mcve]

Did it work without that property and only "stop working" when you added it?
If you've already consumed the entire topic without that config, and there's no new data, then you must reset your consumer group to reread the data
Similarly, if there is no active producer, consumers start at the end of a topic, by default, and will only poll for new data unless you set auto.offset.reset=earliest
